# What is the efficient way to determine words surrounding a keyword?

Tags: c#

Example:
You have a string as in `var str = "Pete is great and John is happy and Pete is here";`.
The keyword is the word `is`.
Then I want the output to be an array with two tuples as in

```
[(Pete,(great,here)),(John,happy)]
```

Now, I would start with `IndexOf`, go over to `Substring` and end with a `foreach` and tinker with creating a new class to store the subarray (in the example `great,here`) in between.

What is the efficient way regarding lines of code and memory/cpu to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this approach is enough for your requirement. Create a class for your `Searchresult`:

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Descriptions { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Indexes { get; set; }
}
```

Then split the string by white-spaces and take all words before and after the `is`. With the help of LINQ you can use a "one-liner" which is readable if you're familiar with LINQ:

```
var str = "Pete is great and John is happy and Pete is here";
string[] words = str.Split(new string[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
SearchResult[] results = words
    .Select((w, ix) => (Word: w, Index: ix))
    .Where(x => x.Word.Equals("is", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Index > 0 && x.Index < words.Length-1)
    .Select(x => (Identifier: words[x.Index - 1], Description: words[x.Index + 1], x.Index))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
    .Select(g => new SearchResult 
    {
        Identifier = g.Key,
        Indexes = g.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray(),
        Descriptions = g.Select(x => x.Description).ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Results(LinqPad):

[image]

You might want to add punctuation marks like `[,;:.!?]` etc. in the split-array.

If you don't want to use LINQ, fill a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` in a  loop.